# Rails 4 Undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model method which has a local variable defined before an `.each` block. The block then iterates over an Array and increases the count based on whether something is `true` or not. The variable in question is `true_count`. I am getting an "undefined local variable" error for `true_count` that I cannot figure out. I am also relatively new to Rails and coding.

project.rb:

```
def displaycount
  d = [self.backlog_display, self.committed_display, self.qa_display, self.started_display, self.completed_display, self.accepted_display]
  true_count == 0
    d.each do |d|
      if d == true
        true_count += 1
      end
    end
end
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a comparison rather than a definition with your variable...

`true_count == 0` needs to be `true_count = 0`

Comment: Thank you! I think I tried that but had forgotten to restart the server after making the code change. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here in this line

```
true_count == 0
```

It should be `true_count = 0`

**Why?**

**`==`** is used for comparison,for example

```
if a == 0

puts 'a is zero'

else

puts 'a is not Zero'

end
```

And `=` is just used to assign a value ta variable.For example

```
a=0 #Here is defined as Zero
```

Hope it Helped!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from:

```
true_count == 0
```

to:

```
true_count = 0
```

You need to assign the variable, rather than check whether or not it's equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
def display_count
  [ backlog_display, 
    committed_display, 
    qa_display, 
    started_display, 
    completed_display, 
    accepted_display].inject(0) {|result,display| result + ( display ? 1 : 0 )  }
end
```